# Google Apps Script - insert second table on a new page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

What I am trying to do is:

- On page 1, insert table 1
- Move to page 2, insert table 2

I am able to insert two tables one after the other but unable to break to a new page before inserting table 2.

```
  docId = "YOUR_DOC_ID";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var table1 = body.insertTable(2, data[0]);
  formatTable(table1);

  // insert page break here

  var table2 = body.insertTable(3, data[1]);
  formatTable(table2);

  doc.saveAndClose();
```

The insertPageBreak() is what I am struggling with.

What I have tried till now:

- The only `appendPageBreak` I could find is on `body`. So I tried `body.appendPageBreak()`. This inserts a new page at the "very" end. BUT I require it right after table 1.
- I read [THIS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/page-break) documentation but could not implement it due to lack of examples I guess.
- For [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736069/google-app-script-page-break-at-cursor) answer, I get NULL for `getCursor()` command. Also `theElement.insertPageBreak(0)` failed for me since element did not show any `insertPageBreak()` method.
- For [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984371/2296728) answer, as mentioned above, appends at the end.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about your actual Document, if new Document is used, how about this modification? The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Insert a table 1.
2. Insert a page break.
3. Insert a table 2 to the new page created by the page break.

#### Modified script 1:

In this script, the table 1, the page break and the table 2 are put in order to the new Document.

```
docId = "###";
var body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
var table1 = body.insertTable(1, [["table1"]]);
body.insertPageBreak(2);
var table2 = body.insertTable(3, [["table2"]]);
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this script, by giving the insert index, the table 1, the page break and the table 2 are put from the insert index in order to the Document.

```
var insertIndex = 1; // Please set this
docId = "###";
var body = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getBody();
var table1 = body.insertTable(insertIndex, [["table1"]]);
var pageBreak = body.insertPageBreak(body.getChildIndex(table1) + 1);
var table2 = body.insertTable(body.getChildIndex(pageBreak.getParent()) + 1, [["table2"]]);
```

#### Note:

- I couldn't understand about `_insertPageBreak()`.

#### References:

- [insertTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex-cells)
- [insertPageBreak()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertpagebreakchildindex)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. You come up with the best solutions. Thank you for your detailed answer and the perfect solution. You have some amazing google apps script skills.

Comment: `_insertPageBreak()`. this was simply a function to add page break. I have updated the code in my question to change the function to simple comment to make it easier for future users to understand the problem.

Comment: @urwaCFC Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I could also understand about ``_insertPageBreak()``. Thank you, too.